# adding values to specific elements using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, extjs

I have MANY input elements that are created dynamically. I want to get all elements that are not disabled, and add a border color to them. From the CSS, I can get all that are disabled doing like this:

```
    input[type="text"][disabled] {
    border-color: black;
}
```

This works perfectly.

I have tried to get those that are not disabled doing this:

```
    input[type="text"][enabled] {
    border-color: green;
}
```

This does not work for some reason, and I am not getting an error.

The reason why I don't want to use JS/JQuery, is that the browser ends up using more than 100% of the CPU on page load.
The guilty code looks like this:

```
var elements = $(":input");
var elementsVisible = elements.prop("disabled");

if(!elementsVisible) { 
    $(this).css("border-color", "green") : 
}
```

How do I get the enabled input fields from CSS file? I am using Extjs by the way. If it is possible and has more benefits to it using JS/JQuery than CSS, I am listening :-)

Comment: get rid of the [enabled] and put the disabled css after the normal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
input[type="text"] {
  background-color: green;
}
input[type="text"][disabled] {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="text_1" />
<br />
<input type="text" name="text_1" disabled/>
<br />
<input type="text" name="text_1" />
<br />
<input type="text" name="text_1" disabled/>
<br />
<input type="text" name="text_1" />
```

EDIT: Even though both `[disabled]` and `:disabled` work the same way, I'd use `:disabled`. Kept it as close to your code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just put both

```
input[attr=value] { // your style definitions }
```

Followed by

```
input[attr=value][disabled] { // your style definitions }
```

In the same file. Everything will use the first rule instead of items that are disabled which will use the second.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine for me, enabled fields are lightgreen, and disabled one is lightgray:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style> 
        input[type=text] {
            background: red;
        }
        input[type=text]:enabled {
            background: lightgreen;
        }
        input[type=text]:disabled {
            background: lightgray;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        First name: <input type="text" value="Mickey"><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" value="Mouse"><br>
        Country: <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="Disneyland">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently the first rule with "red" is ignored, but if you remove the :enabled CSS rule, then the default one applies and enabled inputs turn to red.

```css
input[type=text] {
  background: red;
}
input[type=text]:enabled {
  background: lightgreen;
}
input[type=text]:disabled {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  First name: <input type="text" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" value="Mouse"><br>
  Country: <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="Disneyland">
</form>
```